# Disable Jquery in certain sections

Tags: javascript, jquery, sections

I added cool css menu from one website, it uses jquery version 2. and above, but I had my own custom elements which now works not properly with that version, IE always drops error on that jquery, I wonder if I could disable jquery in some sections of page, for example

```
<div>jquery version 2.* enabled here</div> <div>jquery is disabled here</div>
```

so that I can use my own custom elements without touching jquery functions.

Comment: you can have a look at jQuery.noConflict() option

Comment: if i will rename whole jquery unminified lib, rename all functions, by adding some postfix. will this help theoricaly?

Answer (score 0):

No you can not. Use the latest jQuery 1.x, which will work for both.

http://jquery.com/download/#jquery-1-x

Comment: but it didn't, when i use it it says '$' is undefined or something,forgot.

Comment: i need to run 2 jquery libraries, my custom controls work with jquery 2.x, but this element which i added uses old version of jquery, and exception is kind of "could not set property of 'something', because it's null"

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly Then adjust your code to work with the latest jQuery... making it work for both versions of jQuery isn't a fix... in fact you're creating yourself more work and troubles by doing so...